# How to make my 'robots.txt for face' question more focused and answerable?

Tags: discussion

While I made my best efforts to make my question [Can robots.txt for your face be made effective?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34610/can-robots-txt-for-your-face-be-made-effective?noredirect=1#comment53778_34610) focused and useful, since it address a currently open problem it is very difficult to keep it constructive enough, maybe since the directions are not yet established.

Could you provide some suggestions on how to improve it to be more focused and answerable, and point out the issues causing it to currently be hard to answer?

I *really* would like to make it a useful question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your question asks about ways to do something that currently don't exist. Google is one of those at the forefront of research in this area, but simply put, the question you have asked is likely to be technically unanswerable for some time, and the legal aspects are entirely off topic here.

Your final line is also not going to fit here:

> Are there any other ongoing technical, legal or social attempts to address this conflict?

Have a read of the [faq] and see if there is something in your question which could fit here. I have closed your question for now.

Comment: well said, thanks! by the way your profile picture is kind of an answer :P too. I don't understand something, while physical security seems to a crucial part of being secure, the faq seem be written from a more virtual point of view. I consider privacy an aspect that can be both physical and virtual. And also an aspect of security, eg. it protects individual peace and freedom. Btw., Glass definitely goes far beyond simply being virtual.

Comment: The FAQ is not focused on anything virtual - our aim with this site is to tackle practical issues faced by information security professionals. This does include privacy, physical security, IT controls, compliance etc - but we don't cover legal, as it is too big an area, with too many differing laws in different regions, and we aren't lawyers :-)